# How to get progress of a file uploading in angular2 without using XMLHTTPRequest

Tags: angular, xmlhttprequest

I'm migrating and app I started to develop in angular 1.5 to angular 2.3.

I have a section where the user can upload images and he can see the progress of the uploader. Originally I build it directly with XMLHTTPRequest, but in angular2 the page is being refreshed after the XMLHTTPRequest.

I post a question about that in [Angular2 is refreshing the page when doing a post with XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42289490/angular2-is-refreshing-the-page-when-doing-a-post-with-xmlhttprequest) but as I didn't get any answer after several days, I'm trying to cahnge the approach.

Is it possible to submit a file using a post and get the percentage of the progress? I need to send it to a backend with an authorization header with a JWT token, so I'm not sure if the ng-upload package is useful for me.

[[All the code is in the shared link]] 
[Angular2 is refreshing the page when doing a post with XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42289490/angular2-is-refreshing-the-page-when-doing-a-post-with-xmlhttprequest)

Comment: It's possible to upload progress and you can also add auth headers with this module - http://valor-software.com/ng2-file-upload/

Comment: @Dylan thanks for that, I didn't know that I can added the header there... Anyway, The page is refreshed after the upload for that method too... I added the backend code in the other question just in case it can be generated by the backend...

Comment: I think I can check you answer as the correct one as you anser the scope of my question.. But if you can give me a hand with the issue I'm still having, I'll appreciate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use angular2 http API for tracking upload/download progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42231123/how-to-use-angular2-http-api-for-tracking-upload-download-progress)